# How do I merge 2 json of these type in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

- First JSON in input

  ```
  var obj1 = [{
                  "name":"manu",
                  "age":23,
                  "occupation":"SE"
              },
              {   
                  "name":"test",
                  "age":22,
                  "occupation":"TE"
              }
             ];
  ```

  - Second JSON in input

    ```
     var obj2 = [{
                "age":23,
                "name":"manu",
                "gender":"male"
            },
            {   
                "age":22,
                "name":"test",
                "gender":"male"
            }
           ];
    ```
  - Resulting JSON required after merging

    ```
    var result = [{
                "name":"manu",
                "age":23,
                "occupation":"SE",
                "gender":"male"
            },
            {   
                "name":"test",
                "age":22,
                "occupation":"TE",
                "gender":"male"
            }
           ];
    ```
  - please see the arrangement in which keys are arranged in JSON
  - They are not in same order (age and name ) keys in object

Comment: What's the question? Also why would one care about sequences of keys?

Comment: In Javascript, objects have no order. For merging, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically).

Comment: Hashes keys order is implementation defined, so nothing you can do about their order actually :(

Comment: I am using Object.assign(merged, obj1, obj2) but it doesn't work

Comment: Loop on the array before merging.

Comment: Got the result by looping over the array :)

Comment: But I am getting an array of arrays.... I am looking for an array of objects

Comment: Got the array of objects as well ... now just need to sort them on the basis of some particular columns

Answer (score 1):

You could use a special callback for merging the arrays to a new one `result` with the matching `key` and all other properties.

```js
function mergeTo(target, key) {
    var ref = Object.create(null);
    return function (o) {
        if (!ref[o[key]]) {
            ref[o[key]] = {};
            target.push(ref[o[key]]);
        }
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            ref[o[key]][k] = o[k];
        });
    };
}

var obj1 = [{ "name": "manu", "age": 23, "occupation": "SE" }, { "name": "test", "age": 22, "occupation": "TE" }],
    obj2 = [{ "age": 23, "name": "manu", "gender": "male" }, { "age": 22, "name": "test", "gender": "male" }],
    result = [],
    merge = mergeTo(result, 'name');

obj1.forEach(merge);
obj2.forEach(merge);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two arrays where each index in the array is an object.
If the array indexes go together, as in your example, then just loop and assign.

```
var length = obj1.length;
for( var idx = 0; idx < length; idx++ )
{
  var tmpObj = obj2[ idx ];
  Object.keys(tmpObj).forEach(function(key,index)
  {
     // key: the name of the object key
     // index: the ordinal position of the key within the object 

     // create new object property based upon the variable key
     // and assign it the corresponding value from obj2
     obj1[ idx ][ key ] = tmpObj.key;
  });
}
```

[Iterate over Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

[Using variables as key names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)